Angular NPM Package Without SRC Folder in Path
I have a simple npm package.
In the src folder it contains a single component, but there will be more. I have the following:
src/
|-- general/ (foler)
|------simple-component/ (folder)
|----------index.ts
|----------ng-package.json
|----------public-api.ts
|----------<other files>
|------index.ts
|------ng-package.json
|------public-api.ts

The problem is that when I build the package, it keeps src in the path of the package
example: @mycomponent/lib-name/src/general/simple-component
I have tried altering the angular.json, baseUrl, and rootDir. I have also tried adding paths to the tsconfig.json file and altering the the entryfile of the ng-package.json file at the root level and the src folder level.
I know that I can remove the src folder and have everything reside in the root dir, but I was hoping to keep everything under the src folder umbrella.
Is this possible?
